# What's the condition for a plane and a line to be coplanar in 3D?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry

Please correct me if I'm wrong, but given a plane expressed in point-normal form, and a line expressed in parametric form, an easy way of finding the intersection (or lack of it) is substituting the $(x, y, z)$ values given by the line equation into the equation of the plane. If a real value is found for the parameter, that means the line and the plane intersect on a single point, which can be found by substituting the value found for the parameter into the equation of the line. If when intersecting the line and plane we reach a result such as $1=0$, we know the line does not intersect the plane. **So far so good.** *But...* what would happen if the plane and the line are coplanar? That is, there are infinite solutions to their intersection?

*Examples:*

**i.** $ \pi) \ x +y+z=3, \ r)\left\{\begin{matrix}
  x=3\lambda
 & \\ y=2\lambda
 & \\ z=\lambda
\end{matrix}\right.$

Substituting gives $\lambda = 0.5$

Thus $ \ pi \cap r = P(1.5,1,0.5)$

**ii.** $ \pi) \ x +y+z=3, \ r)\left\{\begin{matrix}
  x=-0.5\lambda
 & \\ y=-0.5\lambda
 & \\ z=\lambda
\end{matrix}\right.$

Substituting gives $0=3$

Thus $ \ pi \cap r = \varnothing$

Comment: If you have a plane $ax+by+cz=d$ with $u=(a,b,c)$ and the line is defined as parallel to $u’=(a’,b’,c’)$ there are three cases: 1) $u\times{}u’=0$ and either a) the plane contains the line or b) the line and plane are disjoint 2) $u\times{}u’\ne{}0$ and you have just one point of intersection.

Comment: @Carlos Gruss The minimum distance between any point in the line and the plane is constant.

Comment: @Narasimham I like that condition, but (excuse my ignorance), how would you write mathematically the minimum distance between any point in the line and the plane?

Comment: Vectors representing a general line and a vector connecting  a point on it to reference point should have zero dot product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the line given parametrically by $\mathbf p_0+t\mathbf v$ lies on the plane $ax+by+cz=\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf p=d$ then $\mathbf p_0$ must satisfy the equation of the plane, i.e., $\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf p_0=d$, and its direction vector $\mathbf v$ must be perpendicular to the plane’s normal $\mathbf n$, so that $\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf v=0$. Therefore, when you substitute into the plane’s equation, you will get $$\mathbf n\cdot(\mathbf p_0+t\mathbf v) = d \\ \mathbf n\cdot\mathbf p_0 + t(\mathbf n\cdot\mathbf v) = d \\ d = d.$$

Answer (score 1):

Consider $$\pi) \ x +y+z=3, \ r)\left\{\begin{matrix}
  x=3\lambda
 & \\ y=2\lambda
 & \\ z=3-5\lambda
\end{matrix}\right.$$

You will get $3=3$ for every $\lambda$.

Comment: OK, I see now, thank you. So in this case, $\pi \cap r = r$, right?

Comment: Correct. That means every  point of the line is also a point on the plane.

Answer (score 0):

Given a general line and plane as such:

$ \pi) \ ax +by+cz=d, \\ r)\left\{\begin{matrix}
  x=p_1+v_1\lambda
 & \\ y=p_2+v_2\lambda
 & \\ z=p_3+v_3\lambda
\end{matrix}\right.$

There are two possible cases for the line and plane to be coplanar:

**i.** $(ap_1 +bp_2 + cp_3) = 0\ \ $, $(av_1 +bv_2 + cv_3) = 0\ \ $ and $ \ d = 0$

**ii.** $(ap_1 +bp_2 + cp_3) \ne 0\ \ $, $(d - ap_1 -bp_2 - cp_3) = 0\ \ $ and $(av_1 +bv_2 + cv_3) = 0\ \ $

In both cases, $\pi \cap r = r$.